# Insert Substring Values into SQL Temp Table Using While Loop?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called accountNumbers. An example of values in the table are:

01-005-000-000-001-000

01-005-311-097-000

001-005-105-545

What I want to do is split the column (accountNum) at the dash, and then insert that value into a temp table, #test. When printing out #test, it should look like:

01

005

000

001

311

097

and so on. I cannot use store procedures or functions. I can get the first value, but any while loop I try just prints that first row over and over again.

```
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > (select count(*) from dbo.accountNumbers
BEGIN
  insert into #test (split, accountNum)
  select SUBSTRING(accountNum, 1, CHARINDEX('-', accountNum) -1), accountNum
  from dbo.accountNumbers
END
```

Comment: You have an endless (and rather pointless) loop there. You should look into better ways of splitting that string. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I've read that page, but since I can't use functions, I can't figure out a better solution besides substring. And yes, I know the loop is kind of pointless; I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Why can't you use a function or a stored procedure? That seems to be a rather arbitrary restriction.

Comment: As far as I understand, I can't use a function or stored procedure because this query is going to be inserted into another db table itself. It's then read by a program with strict parameters in order to be run. It doesn't get run independently.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction of no functions or procedures seems a little strange but you don't have to use a function to do this. A VERY minor tweak to the XML function found here http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings can be utilized so you don't need a function to do this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#something') is not null
    drop table #something

create table #something
(
    AccountNumbers varchar(100)
)
insert #something
select '01-005-000-000-001-000' union all
select '01-005-311-097-000' union all
select '001-005-105-545'

select *
from #something s
cross apply
(
    SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(s.AccountNumbers, '-', '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
)MySplit
```